# Stored procedure error handling best practise

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that calls into multiple other stored procedures. If the stored procedure hits an error, does it exit or continue to execute rest of code?

How can I ensure that if one section fails it prints the failed stored procedure and will continue to execute the next one.

E.g

```
"spInsert_1 fail"
"spInsert_2 sucess"
```

Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertAll] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    exec dbo.spInsert_1
    exec dbo.spInsert_2
    exec dbo.spInsert_3
END
```

Comment: I don't know much about this (thus I do not know if it is the most efficient which it probably is not) but you could try to use `try catch`...https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

Comment: From link it looks as if il need a try catch for each exec statement.

Comment: Actually, if you look a little further down from the top it tells you how to get the error.  There is a way to see which procedure caused the error.  So, in theory, you could have one big `TRY CATCH` over your procedures.  Again, I have not used it before so this is me guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically SQL Server will do that for you by default - However you may want to do the in more elegant way. Here is the way

**Stored procedure 1**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp1]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
    SELECT 1 
    PRINT 'SP1 is completed'
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'SP 1 is Failed'
    END CATCH'
END
```

**Stored procedure 2** (which will generate the error)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp2]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRY
SELECT 1/0 
PRINT 'SP2 is completed'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
PRINT 'SP 2 is Failed'
END CATCH
END
```

**Stored procedure 3**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp3]
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
    SELECT 1 
    PRINT 'SP 3 is completed'
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'SP 3 is Failed'
    END CATCH
END
```

**Main stored procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Mainsp
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    EXEC dbo.sp1 
    EXEC dbo.sp2 
    EXEC dbo.sp3
END
GO
```

**Message when you will execute main procedure**

```
 SP 1 is completed 
 SP 2 is Failed 
 SP 3 is completed
```

Even if you don't use TRY-CATCH then also SQL will do the execution of stored procedure in the desired way. The only difference you will see is the success/failure message.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated

Comment: Note all errors are not caught,since all sps are in same batch,failure in one sp can terminate whole batch

Comment: @TheGameiswar Is it possible to `TRY CATCH` all three `EXEC` and use the `ERROR_PROCEDURE()` to display which one had the error?

Comment: @Cody360c yes you can keep in that way also. You can use like **BEGIN TRY
  -- your code 
  PRINT 'SP1 EXECUTED SUCCESSFULL'
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
  SELECT  
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
    ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
    ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
    ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
    ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
    ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage; 
 END CATCH**

Comment: or alternatively, you can remove TRY-CATCH from SP1, SP2 and SP3 and put them in MAIN SP **BEGIN TRY
  EXEC dbo.sp1 
  PRINT 'SP1 EXECUTED SUCCESSFULL'
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
  SELECT  
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
    ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
    ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
    ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
    ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
    ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage; 
 END CATCH** and so.. on....

Comment: @AnujTripathi Gotcha.  Thanks.  I haven't used it in SQL before so I wasn't sure.  : )